# abstract type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions'1' is not accessible for inheritance - UnitTests

Tags: c#, .net, xunit, justmock

I have a small problem with running the unit tests with dotnet CLI. I am using xUnit and JustMock.

I have a class called 'DevOpsOptions' which is a internal and located in UserManagement project.

Example:

```
    internal class DevOpsOptions
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

I also have another project for unit tests, called UserManagement.Tests. I added reference to the UserManagement project and set InternalVisibility

Example:

```
<ItemGroup>
        <InternalsVisibleTo Include="$(AssemblyName).Tests" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I wrote a test that runs successfully if run the standard way. Right click -> Run tests
Example:

```
        [Fact]
        public async void ThrowArgumentException_WhenUserEmailIsNull()
        {
            //Arrange
            HttpClient httpClient = Mock.Create<HttpClient>();
            ClientOptions clientApplicationOptions = Mock.Create<ClientOptions>();
            IOptions<DevOpsOptions> devOpsOptions = Mock.Create<IOptions<DevOpsOptions>>();
            AzureDevOpsSettings azureDevOpsSettings = new AzureDevOpsSettings();

            IHttpDevOpsServiceClient httpDevOpsServiceClient = new HttpDevOpsServiceClient(httpClient, clientApplicationOptions, devOpsOptions);

            //Act
            async Task actAsync() => await httpDevOpsServiceClient.DeleteUser(null, azureDevOpsSettings);

            //Assert
            await Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentException>(actAsync);
        }
```

But when i try to run the test with dotnet command

```
dotnet test .\UserManagement.Test.csproj
```

Its throw this exception:

```
Abstract type Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions'1[Models.DevOpsOptions] is not accessible for inheritance
```

But when i change Model type to public, everything is fine.